# How to solve 403 forbidden when the request is legal, but the server refuses response?

Tags: java, primavera

How to solve 403 forbidden when the request is legal, but the server refuses response?

I just started studying APIs with Java, Spring and Postman so I'm having some difficulties. A few days ago I made a request that returned the following error: "The request was a legal request, but the server is refusing to respond to it. Unlike a 401 Unauthorized response, authenticating will make no difference." I already tried to follow the instructions of other questions, but with no success.

I will leave the controller class to help you understand, thanks for your attention!

class controller:

```
import com.altercode.gaminiconblog.dto.RegisterRequest;
import com.altercode.gaminiconblog.service.AuthService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/auth")
public class AuthController {
@Autowired
private AuthService authService;

@RequestMapping("/signup")
public ResponseEntity signup(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
    authService.signup(registerRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);

}
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.altercode</groupId>
    <artifactId>gaminicon-blog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gaminicon-blog</name>
    <description>projeto para o sistema de blogs do gaminicon</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency><!-- htt
    ps://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you include your pom as well ?

Comment: @Maickeen it's included!

Comment: Maybe try to debug where it's exactly failing or throwing some kind of ForbiddenException (since you mentioned 403). My assumption would be that "    authService.signup(registerRequest)" this service method code might help us understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Spring Security, it will auto enable a CSFR protection, if you don`t expect to receive a CSFR token, just disable it.

To disable CSFR protection, create a class like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the info, I had already created SecurityConfig previously! I'm going to try to redo it.

Comment: @Morttem_Fracktion, if it worked, please mark the answer as accepted =D